# How i can add style of a existent component in styled components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to use styled components to personalize a header component from semantic-ui-react.

I try:

**header.jsx:**

```
import React  from 'react';

import { Header } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import TipografiaHeader  from './cabecalho.css'


const HeaderPages = () => (
    <div>
        <TipografiaHeader as='h2'
        textAlign='center'
        >
            Workout Log
        </TipografiaHeader>
    </div>
  )

export default HeaderPages
```

**cabecalho.jss.js:**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Header } from 'semantic-ui-react';


const TipografiaHeader = styled.Header`
    background: red;
`;

export { TipografiaHeader };
```

But in the console i'm receiving:

> Uncaught TypeError: _styledComponents2.default.Header is not a
>   function

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `styled.element` can only be used for HTML elements. For eg:

```
styled.h1``
```

For styling a custom component, the syntax to be used is:

```
styled(Header)``
```

Note that this custom component requires the `className` prop to be passed into the DOM element underneath for this to work.

[Docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component)